# Proof that $\frac{dx\ dy}{x^2+y^2}$ is a Haar measure on the multiplicative group $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

How can it be proven that for every Borel subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ as A we have $\mu(cA)=\mu(A)$?
$$
∬_{cA} \frac{dx\ dy}{x^2+y^2}=\iint_{A} \frac{dx\ dy}{x^2+y^2}
$$
I'm confused...

Comment: @JMCF125 : Where you wrote C\setminus{0} you need C\setminus\{0\}.  The braces will be invisible in the first form because of the special role that braces have in TeX, LaTeX, and MathJax.  (I changed it).

Comment: @MichaelHardy, you're right, I was distracted. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: A sort of reflex tells me that if one writes $u=cx$ and $v=cy$ then one gets $du=x\,dx$ and $dv=c\,dy$, so $\dfrac{dx\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $\dfrac{du\,dv}{u^2+v^2}$ (since $c^2$ is a factor in both the numerator and the denominator, so it cancels), and if $(x,y)\in A$ then $(u,v)\in cA$.  But writing a rigorous proof takes a bit more.

Comment: I think that x=cu.is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dxdy⁄(x^2+y^(2 ) )is a Haar measure on the multiplicative group nonzero complex numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753012/dxdyx2y2-is-a-haar-measure-on-the-multiplicative-group-nonzero-complex)

Answer (score 3):

Note $\mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}\bar{z}$

(edit: I think I have the sign wrong: $\mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = -\frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}\bar{z}$. This error doesn't affect the argument below)

I will instead prove the following: if I make the substitution $z = cw$, then

$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}\bar{z}
&= \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{d}(cw) \, \mathrm{d}(\overline{cw})
\\&=\frac{1}{2i} c \mathrm{d}w \, \bar{c} d\overline{w}
\\&= \frac{\|c\|^2}{2 i} \mathrm{d}w \, \mathrm{d}\bar{w}
\end{align}$$

Consequently,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}\bar{z}}{2i \|z\|^2} 
= \frac{\mathrm{d}w \, \mathrm{d}\bar{w}}{2i \|w\|^2} $$

and thus this differential form is invariant under the transformation $z \mapsto cz$ for any nonzero complex $c$.

Comment: This is a very nice way.thank you

Comment: Thanks. I really like making this switch from $(x,y)$ to $(z, \bar{z})$ whenever I can, since it lets us leverage the calculus of complex numbers to make calculations a lot simpler.

Comment: thanks for your help.I could not show dxdy=-1/2idzdz.but The rest will help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice general result (see Folland's Real Analysis, Chapter 11, Exercises 3 and 4): if you have two elements $g,h\in G$ (where $G$ is locally compact of course) and the action of $g$ on $h$ (by left multiplication) can be written as $A_gh+b_{g}$, where $A_g$ is a linear transformation and $b_{g}$ is an affine part (meaning $g$ action on $h$ is an affine mapping), then the Haar measure is given by $\frac{1}{|\det(A_g)|}$. This tacitly assumes that $G$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in some way and comes from a change of variable (hence the occurrence of something resembling a Jacobian). I'll illustrate this with your example so it is clearer.

In your case if $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, then write $z_1 = x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2 = x_2+iy_2$. What you have then is that $z_1z_2 = x_1x_2-y_1y_2 + i(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)$. We can view this as a matrix product (associating the real part to the first coordinate and imaginary part to the second coordinate):

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & -y_1 \\ y_1 & x_1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_2 \\ y_2\end{array}\right).$$

Then $A_{z_1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & -y_1 \\ y_1 & x_1\end{array}\right)$ and $b_{z_1} = 0$. It's easy to see that $\det(A_{z_1}) = x_1^2+y_1^2$ which immediately gives you your result.

Alternatively: show that

$$\int_{\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}}\frac{f(x,y)}{x^2+y^2}\,dxdy$$

is left-invariant. By the construction of the Haar measure we know that left-invariant measures correspond to left-invariant integrals and vice versa so this is an easy check. The above technique is used for *constructing* the Haar measure for simple examples but it is not necessary to do that if all you need to do is check something is a Haar measure.

Comment: Thank you very much., With your explanation, I understood the meaning of the proposition 2.21 of folland. For left invariant

Comment: No problem :). It's tricky business for sure.

Comment: For left invariant my opinion and Michael Hardy's description is correct?

Comment: Fundamentally, yes Michael's intuition is correct. The above is the justification for that.